# Getting Error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android

I get the following error when running the code.

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

```
JSONObject data = ((JSONObject) response.get("data"));
String setting_name =  data.getString("setting_name");
String setting_value = data.getString("setting_value");
```

Comment: "data" is not a json object! {"data": "mydata"} is a jsonobject.

Answer (score 2):

First get you Data as a string try printing it to make sure it contain JSON... then pass it into JSONObject after which you will be able to retrieve JSON object like you mentioned.

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(YOUR-STRING-GOES-HERE);
```

After which you can do.

```
String setting_name =  data.getString("setting_name");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `response.get("data");` type is a `String` representing a *JSON*. So in order to get a `JSONObject` from it, you need to *parse* it first.

You achieve that by calling the following *constructor* from `JSONObject` class:

```
JSONObject(String json);
```

*Creates a new **JSONObject** with name/value mappings from the JSON string.*

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting it to JSONObject?

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response.get("data"));
```

Beyond that its hard to say without seeing the more code/json data.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the string is a valid JSON. You can user JSONObject parameterized constructor with the given string to convert the JSON string to a valid JSON object.

For example,

```
String jsonString = "{'setting_name': 'volume', 'setting_value':10}"; 
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String setting_name = data.getString("setting_name"); //gives volume
String setting_value = data.getString("setting_value"); //gives 10
```